# Compute x**k with x, k being arrays of arbitrary dimensionality

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays: One array `x` with shape `(n, a0, a1, ...)` and one array `k` with shape `(n, b0, b1, ...)`. I would like to compute and array of exponentials such that the output has dimension `(a0, a1, ..., b0, b1, ...)` and

```
out[i0, i1, ..., j0, j1, ...] == prod(x[:, i0, i1, ...] ** k[:, j0, j1, ...])
```

If there is only one `a_i` and one `b_j`, broadcasting does the trick via

```
import numpy

x = numpy.random.rand(2, 31)
k = numpy.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, 101))

out = numpy.prod(x[..., None]**k[:, None], axis=0)
```

If `x` has a few dimensions more, more `None`s have to be added:

```
x = numpy.random.rand(2, 31, 32, 33)
k = numpy.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, 101))

out = numpy.prod(x[..., None]**k[:, None, None, None], axis=0)
```

If `x` has a few dimensions more, more `None`s have to be added at other places:

```
x = numpy.random.rand(2, 31)
k = numpy.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, 51, 51))

out = numpy.prod(x[..., None, None]**k[:, None], axis=0)
```

How to make the computation of `out` generic with respect to the dimensionality of the input arrays?

Comment: i want to know this tooooooo.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one using `reshaping` of the two arrays so that they are broadcastable against each other and then performing those operations and `prod` reduction along the first axis -

```
k0_shp = [k.shape[0]] + [1]*(x.ndim-1) + list(k.shape[1:])
x0_shp = list(x.shape) + [1]*(k.ndim-1)
out = (x.reshape(x0_shp) ** k.reshape(k0_shp)).prod(0)
```

Here's another way to reshape both inputs to `3D` allowing one singleton dim per input and such that they are broadcastable against each other, perform `prod` reduction to get `2D` array, then reshape back to multi-dim array -

```
s = x.shape[1:] + k.shape[1:] # output shape
out = (x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1,1)**k.reshape(k.shape[0],1,-1)).prod(0).reshape(s)
```

It must be noted that reshaping merely creates a view into the input array and as such is virtually free both memory-wise and performance-wise.

Answer (score 4):

Without understanding fully the math of what you're doing, it seems that you need a constant number of None's for the number of dimensions of each x and k.

does something like this work?

```
out = numpy.prod(x[[...]+[None]*(k.ndim-1)]**k[[slice(None)]+[None]*(x.ndim-1)])
```

Here are the slices separately so they're a bit easier to read:

```
x[  [...] + [None]*(k.ndim-1)  ]

k[  [slice(None)] + [None]*(x.ndim-1)  ]
```

#### Compatibility Note:

`[...]` seems to only be valid in python 3.x If you are using 2.7 (I haven't tested lower) substitute `[Ellipsis]` instead:

```
x[  [Ellipsis] + [None]*(k.ndim-1)  ]
```

Comment: `[...]` is only valid in Python 3. Perhaps there's an expression to make it compatible with Python 2 as well?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer good catch, I made the switch to 3.6 a bit ago and tend to forget to test in 2.7 as well... see edit